# One-To-Many relationship deletes foreign key in Doctrine

Tags: php, database, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This is driving me crazy.

A `Client` can have many `Vehicle`s.

This is a one to many relationship. When trying to save the entities I get an error saying that the foreign key is null. When I remove the Doctrine relation and store the `Vehicle` separately everything is working fine.

This is how I created the relation:

```
class Vehicle {

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="vehicles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $client;

}

class Client {

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->vehicles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vehicle", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $vehicles;

}
```

I try to save the entities like this:

```
$client = new Client();
$vehicle = new Vehicle();
$client->getVehicles()->add($vehicle);
$em->persist($client);
$em->flush();
```

Next I get a PDO exception saying that `client_id` can't be `null` on the `Vehicle` table.

It seems like Doctrine is not copying the foreign key correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `persist()` the `$vehicle` somewhere?

Comment: @andy No, that should not be needed since I'm doing the `cascade={"persist"}`

Comment: Ah, right. Checking the code in detail: `public $client` might cause issues at least with proxies for older versions of Doctrine.

Comment: @andy ok, let me try that tomorrow when am back in the office

Comment: @andy All of the instance variables are not `private` (as they should be, of course) but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Does it work when you persist each entity separately? How is `$id` annotated?

Comment: @andy [I was able to solve the issue](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys) (I slighty modified the example to hide business relevant code). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

According to [their docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys):

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys.
>
> Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

Obviously you need a different approach.

A solution is given in their example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE product (
>     id INTEGER,
>     name VARCHAR,
>     PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
> CREATE TABLE product_attributes (
>     product_id INTEGER,
>     attribute_name VARCHAR,
>     attribute_value VARCHAR,
>     PRIMARY KEY (product_id, attribute_name)
> );
> ```
>
> This schema should be mapped to a Product Entity as follows:
>
> ```
> class Product
> {
>     private $id;
>     private $name;
>     private $attributes = array();
> }
> ```
>
> Where the `attribute_name` column contains the key and `attribute_value` contains the value of each array element in `$attributes`.